# Issue while attaching slide in the mail attachment using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I am trying to send Google sheet data to a single slide, then convert it into pdf and send it as an attachment via email, all this using Google Apps Script. But the issue is when I attach this slide as a pdf, it does not get an updated slide, which means it gets a template rather than a slide with the updated data from Google sheet, here is the code snippet:

```
function createCertificate(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  if (sheet.getName() === 'SheetName' && range.getColumn() == 9 && e.value == "TRUE") { // Column I (9) is the checkbox column
    var row = range.getRow();
    var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).getDisplayValues()[0]; 
  
    var destinationFolderId = "###";

    var sourceSlideFile = DriveApp.getFileById("###");
    var copiedSlideFile = sourceSlideFile.makeCopy(data[1]+" pdf", DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId));
    
    var newSlide = SlidesApp.openById(copiedSlideFile.getId()).getSlides()[0];
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Full Name}}', data[1]);
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Name of Program}}', data[2]);
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Days}}', data[7]);
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Date of Completion}}', data[6]);
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Date}}', data[0]);


    SlidesApp.openById(copiedSlideFile.getId());
    var pdf = copiedSlideFile.getBlob().getAs("application/pdf");;

    GmailApp.sendEmail('mailAddress', 'Requested pdf', 'Hi there, \n Please find the pdf in the attachment', {attachments:[pdf]});
  
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),range.getColumn()+1).setValue("Sent");
  }
}
```

I apologize if the code is not optimized, Any guidance to resolve this issue and optimized version would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that in your situation, [`saveAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose) is required to be used. But, in the case of your showing script, when the modified script is proposed, it might be useful. So, I show you the modified script using `saveAndClose()` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function createCertificate(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  if (sheet.getName() === 'SheetName' && range.getColumn() == 9 && e.value == "TRUE") { // Column I (9) is the checkbox column
    var row = range.getRow();
    var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).getDisplayValues()[0];

    var destinationFolderId = "###";

    var sourceSlideFile = DriveApp.getFileById("###");
    var copiedSlideFile = sourceSlideFile.makeCopy(data[1] + " pdf", DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId));

    // --- I modified the below script.
    var slide = SlidesApp.openById(copiedSlideFile.getId());
    var newSlide = slide.getSlides()[0];
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Full Name}}', data[1]);
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Name of Program}}', data[2]);
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Days}}', data[7]);
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Date of Completion}}', data[6]);
    newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Date}}', data[0]);
    slide.saveAndClose();
    var pdf = copiedSlideFile.getBlob();
    // ---

    GmailApp.sendEmail('mailAddress', 'Requested pdf', 'Hi there, \n Please find the pdf in the attachment', { attachments: [pdf] });

    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn() + 1).setValue("Sent");
  }
}
```

- In the current stage, in the case of Google Slides, when the Blob is retrieved from Google Slide, the mimeType is automatically changed to `application/pdf`.